# Return pdf from controller and display on front end in spring

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have pdf saved in blob format in my database. It's coming empty on front end.

Here is my controller call:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/viewDocument", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> viewDocument()
{
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = null;
    try{
        File uFile = null;
        uFile = maintainFileService.getDocument(123456L);
        bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(uFile.getFile());
        headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=pdf.pdf");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        logger.error("Exception while viewing the pdf.");
    }
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
            .body(new InputStreamResource(bis));
}
```

And here is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url: "/esubmission/recorder/search/viewDocument" ,
    timeout : 100000,
    success : function(result) {
        window.open(result);
    },
    error : function(e) {
        console.log("ERROR: ", e);
    },
    done : function(e) {
        console.log("DONE");
    }
});
```

I think I am missing something but just couldn't figure it out. TIA

Comment: Is there anyway to bump the post?

Comment: Looks like my call is getting through right , just the pdf is empty now. Updating the code.